# Passing URL parameters to functions in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble passing URL parameters to a function in React with react router. Sorry but I'm new at this. My route is shown below. The function is GetMovies thanks any advice would be helpful.

```js
<BrowserRouter basename={"/MovieStreamingAvailabilityApp"}>
    <Route path={"MovieStreamingAvailabilityApp/:genreId/:sortBy/:page"}>
      <GetMovies />
    </Route>
</BrowserRouter>

import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";

function GetMovies() {
    let genreId = useParams();
    function movieData(genreId = 0, sortBy = "popularity.desc", page = 1){
        const baseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={my_key}&language=en-US&include_adult=false&include_video=false&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate";

    }
}
export default GetMovies;
```

Comment: Sorry but I should have been more clear I meant passing the parameters as arguments to the function

Answer (score 0):

Gotta use this type of string quotations: ``
They're not the single quote ones, they're the tick. On most laptops the key is in the top left, below the tilda.

This allows you to add variables directly to your string with ${VARIABLE_NAME}

So your string would look like this.

`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${my_key}&language=en-US&include_adult=false&include_video=false&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate`;